# How do I calculate the resulting field of a 2f-arrangement?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

I've been trying to proof that the 2f-arrangement for lenses causes a fourier-transform of the original field. After some research I found a hint how to pull it (see [page](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-71-optics-spring-2009/video-lectures/lecture-18-spatial-filtering-lens-transfer-functions-transforms/MIT2_71S09_lec18.pdf) 15), but all my calculations don't give the result given there (for one dimension).

Can someone explain how exactly they get the result?

Comment: Have you tried looking at a resource that's more robust than a set of presentation slides? Say, an optics textbook? (As one place to start: one of the core textbooks, Hecht's *Optics*, has an entire chapter on Fourier optics.) Or, say, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_optics#Fourier_transforming_property_of_lenses)?

Comment: Jap, I've really searched everywhere. Most textbooks say something about it, but non has got a derivation of the formular.